# ToString not updating on object when altering ListBox in VB

Tags: vb.net, class, tostring

I have a form that alters the content of a class within a list box. The information is updated correctly, but my ToString override on my object doesn't refresh - meaning the old ToString doesn't change. How would I fix this?

Here's my object:

```
Public Class Destination
    Public strDestinationName As String
    Public strAddress As String
    Public intQuality As Integer
    Public intPrice As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return strDestinationName
    End Function
End Class
```

Here's the code where it should be updated

```
        Dim selectedDestination As Destination

        selectedDestination = CType(ListForm.lbNames.SelectedItem, Destination)
        selectedDestination.strDestinationName = tbName.Text
        selectedDestination.strAddress = tbAddress.Text
        selectedDestination.intPrice = cbPrice.SelectedIndex
        selectedDestination.intQuality = cbQuality.SelectedIndex

        Me.Close()
```

Comment: Your `ToString` override on your object does refresh. However if you assigned the result of the `ToString` to some other control, then you will have to reassign it manually.

Comment: I do have it assigned to a ListBox control. Is there a way I can update it, or do I need to delete it from the ListBox and add it again?

Comment: Replace the public **Fields** with public **Properties**. Ex, `Public Property DestinationName As String`....

Comment: The concept of assigning the result of the ToString method to the ListBox is nonsense. How EXACTLY did you you populate the control? What you should actually be doing is using properties rather than fields, as suggested above, and then binding a list of your objects and setting the DisplayMember. Your ToString method is then of no use and can be discarded completely.

Comment: If what you actually mean is that you called ToString on each object and added the result to the ListBox then of course you see no change. Once created, those Strings have no connection to your objects at all. That's why you should be binding the objects and let the system get the required data as and when needed. Binding requires properties. There's actually more to it too, but I'm not typing any more while on a phone.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how you add items to a `ListBox`, it is the `ListBox` that actually displays the data. In your case, it appears that you are adding `Destination` objects to the `ListBox` somehow, given that the `SelectedItem` is a `Destination` object. Given that you have written that `ToString` method, you are presumably relying on that to produce the text that the `ListBox` displays for each item. You are now expecting to be able to change the value of the `strDestinationName` field of one of the items and have the `ListBox` reflect that change. How exactly do you think that is going to happen?

The `ToString` method has to be called in order to get the new value and who do you think is going to call it? It would be the `ListBox` that calls it because it is the `ListBox` that displays the result. When you change that field, you are expecting the `ListBox` to call your `ToString` method but why would it do that? What reason has the `ListBox` got to call that method? It has no knowledge of the change you made so why would it think that it has to get new data?

The solution to your problem is to change your code in some way to notify the `ListBox` that data has changed so that it knows that it needs to get that new data and display it. There are multiple ways that you could do that.

The simplest option would be to bind your data to the `ListBox` via a `BindingSource` and then, when you modify an item, call the `ResetItem` method or similar of the `BindingSource`. That will raise an event that is handled by the `ListBox` and the `ListBox` then knows that it needs to refresh the data for that item. That is what will prompt the `ListBox` to call your `ToString` method and get the new data to display. You would add the `BindingSource` to the form in the designer and then do the binding where you are currently adding the items, e.g.

```vb
Dim destinations As New List(Of Destination)

For i = 1 To 10
    Dim d As New Destination

    d.strDestinationName = "Destination " & i
    destinations.Add(d)
Next

destinationBindingSource.DataSource = destinations
destinationListBox.DataSource = destinationBindingSource
```

The modification would look something like this:

```vb
Dim selectedDestination = DirectCast(destinationBindingSource.Current, Destination)

selectedDestination.strDestinationName = "New Destination"
destinationBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem()
```

The `Current` property returns the item currently selected in the bound UI and the `ResetCurrentItem` method notifies the bound UI to refresh the display of that item.

This is really not the best way to go about it though, given that you have control over the item type. What you ought to do is implement the type using properties rather than fields, get rid of the `ToString` method that only returns the value of one property and then add a change event to that property:

```vb
Public Class Destination

    Private _destinationName As String

    Public Property DestinationName As String
        Get
            Return _destinationName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If _destinationName <> value Then
                _destinationName = value
                OnDestinationNameChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Address As String
    Public Property Quality As Integer
    Public Property Price As Integer

    Public Event DestinationNameChanged As EventHandler

    Protected Overridable Sub OnDestinationNameChanged(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent DestinationNameChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can now bind a list of `Destination` objects directly and specify any of those properties as the `DisplayMember` to have that property value displayed:

```vb
Dim destinations As New List(Of Destination)

For i = 1 To 10
    Dim d As New Destination

    d.strDestinationName = "Destination " & i
    destinations.Add(d)
Next

destinationListBox.DisplayMember = "DestinationName"
destinationListBox.DataSource = destinations
```

You don't need the `ToString` method because the `DisplayMember` specifies that the value of the property with that name should be displayed. When you modify the value of the `DestinationName` property of an item, it will raise the `DestinationNameChanged` event and that will notify the `ListBox` that it needs to refresh the display for that item, so you don't need any additional code to make the `ListBox` update.

That's fine if you only plan to modify existing items. There's still a problem if you want to add and/or remove items after binding though. The `List(Of T)` class that is used to bind the items to the control in this example does not have any events to notify the control of changes to the list like that. In that case, you can use a BindingSource again if you want. If you add and remove items via the `BindingSource` then it will raise that appropriate events and the `ListBox` will update. If you wanted to add and remove via the underlying list then you'd have to call an appropriate method of the `BindingSource` when you made a change.

An alternative would be to use a `BindingList(Of Destination)` instead of a `List(Of Destination)`. As the name suggests, the `BindingList(Of T)` class is made for binding, so it will automatically raise the appropriate events when the list changes to enable the UI to update without extra code from you. Using the combination of property change events in your item class and a `BindingList(Of T)`, you can add, edit and remove items in the bound list and the UI will reflect those changes automatically.